# Separation of repeating code - common.h file - declaration of function with custom parameter

Tags: c, compilation

Assuming that I have file A.c and file B.c, I would like to move common code to common.h and common.c files.

File A.c

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    long long nameA;    <--- different member
    struct astruct *next;
} MYSTRUC;

void free_table(MYSTRUC** tab) { <--- same code in A.c and B.c
    int i;
    MYSTRUC* current;
    MYSTRUC* tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++) {
        current = tab[i];
        while (current != NULL) {
            tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    free(tab);
}

MYSTRUC** inittable() {
    int i;
    MYSTRUC **tab;
    ht = (MYSTRUC**) malloc( sizeof(MYSTRUC*) * TSIZE );
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++) tab[i] = (MYSTRUC*) NULL;
    return tab;
}
void otherA2() {uses nameA}
```

File B.c

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    long long nameB;   <---- different member
    struct bstruct *next;
} MYSTRUC;

void free_table(MYSTRUC** tab) {  <--- same code in A.c and B.c
    int i;
    MYSTRUC* current;
    MYSTRUC* tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++) {
        current = tab[i];
        while (current != NULL) {
            tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    free(tab);
}

MYSTRUC** inittable() {
    int i;
    MYSTRUC **tab;
    ht = (MYSTRUC**) malloc( sizeof(MYSTRUC*) * TSIZE );
    for (i = 0; i < TSIZE; i++) tab[i] = (MYSTRUC*) NULL;
    return tab;
}

void otherB2() {uses nameB}
```

If I put a declaration of *free_table()* in common.h, the compiler will complain about unknown type MYSTRUC. I can create files A.h and B.h and move there MYSTRUC (from A.c) and MYSTRUC (from B.c). 
But it will not solve my problem. STRUCT version from the second header will cover version from the first header.

```
File common.h 
#include "A.h" <--- wrong
#include "B.h" <--- wrong

void free_table(MYSTRUC** str){ <--- same code in A.c and B.c
....
}
```

How should I solve this situation? Is it possible to do it without templates?

Comment: *"Is it possible to do it without templates?"* - Since you're using C and not C++, I'd be curious how you'd do it *with* templates.

Comment: Yes, it is C, and yes I don't have templates and I am wondering if I am able to solve it. Code of func_common() is exactly the same but seems that this is form of overloading...

Comment: Members of `MYSTRUC` have identical types and order. Why not just move both the function  and typedef to `common.h`?

Comment: @klutt what if otherA2() uses member nameA and otherB2() uses member nameB?

Comment: Not enough information. If the two structs are actually different, you can't use the same C function. Also don't call them *the same thing*. Depending on what `func_common` does you could maybe rewrite for a common version. Depending on what the structs are, you could maybe design a "base" version that a common function *can use*. Or you can use function pointers to get something like "virtual" methods, "interfaces", etc. of other languages. Or a macro, which is a possibility although messy.

Comment: @flamingo I think you should produce a [mre] unless you want this to be an endless loop of "You can do like this. Ok, but what if? Then you do like this."

Comment: To answer your question in a very generic way: It's often possible to mimic templates in C, but it rarely looks good.

Comment: @klutt, sorry, I modified my question. I am trying to move inittable() and free_table() to a common file.

Comment: To be honest, it seems like you're going over the river for water. If these two functions is the only duplication, then you're fine. Duplication is in general negative, but so is also introducing new headers.

Comment: And which type do you want `inittable` to return? The one from A or B?

Comment: There are another 4 duplicated functions which are not connected to MYSTRUC type. It was the main motivation to create common.h. Now I understand that what I need for inittable() and free_table() is overloading, so I am not able to do it elegantly in C. Thanks for all comments!

Comment: `typedef struct mystruct { struct astruct *next; } MYSTRUC; MYSTRUC* current; current = current->next;` – how do you expect this to compile anyway? Pointer types of `current` and `current->next` are different anyway!

Comment: Are both linked lists? Because if so, you could pack the pointer to next into a common header of both, the header would have a pointer to header inside. You *need* to place this header as first element. Then you could have that common function via pointer to header (struct and first element of struct share the same address). That wouldn't (necessarily) work in C++, by the way. Problem with that, though, is that you'd need casts all the time when iterating the list with other functions relying on the concrete type (*containing* the header)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, I understand that what I am trying to get is function overloading. I will separate functions which are not dependent on the custom type (MYSTRUC) and leave free_table() and init_table() in the current form.

Thank you @klutt, @Fire Lancer, @WhozCraig.